# Android app in while crashes

Tags: android, button, crash, while-loop

My app should start an while when I press a button, and then stop it when i click on that same button. App gets in while and plays sound once and then crashes. Why?

Java code:

```
    metronomepp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ms==0) {ms=1;}
            while (ms == 1) {
                if (metronome.isPlaying()) {metronome.pause();}
                metronome.seekTo(0);
                metronome.setOnSeekCompleteListener(null);
                metronome.start();
                metronome.setOnCompletionListener(null);
                try {
                    wait ((long) timetw);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                metronomepp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("Metronome", "InWhile1");
                        ms=0;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

LogCat after pressing button:

```
03-14 19:10:30.584: I/Metronome clicked(25448): 1
03-14 19:10:30.584: I/Metronome(25448): InWhile
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer(25448): isPlaying: 0
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25448): isPlaying: 0
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25448): seekTo: 0(msec)
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer(25448): seekTo 0
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer(25448): getDuration
03-14 19:10:30.584: V/MediaPlayer(25448): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer(25448): Received seek complete
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer(25448): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer(25448): callback application
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer(25448): back from callback
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25448): start
03-14 19:10:30.589: V/MediaPlayer(25448): start
03-14 19:10:30.619: D/AndroidRuntime(25448): Shutting down VM
03-14 19:10:30.619: W/dalvikvm(25448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c581f8)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at com.example.guitartools.MetronomeActivity$3.onClick(MetronomeActivity.java:72)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-14 19:10:30.624: E/AndroidRuntime(25448):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 19:10:30.969: V/MediaPlayer(25448): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-14 19:10:30.969: V/MediaPlayer(25448): playback complete
03-14 19:10:30.969: V/MediaPlayer(25448): callback application
03-14 19:10:30.969: V/MediaPlayer(25448): back from callback
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). You need a separate thread. You don't want your `UI` thread to `sleep` or `wait`

[Here is a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread/11140429#11140429)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't block the main thread:

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
...
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
```

The recommended approach for Android is to use a Handler and Runnable, like so:

```
metronomepp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (ms==0) {ms=1;}

        if (ms==1) {
            metronomepp.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    metronomepp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.i("Metronome", "InWhile1");
                            ms=0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, timetw);
        }

        while (ms == 1) {
            if (metronome.isPlaying()) {metronome.pause();}
            metronome.seekTo(0);
            metronome.setOnSeekCompleteListener(null);
            metronome.start();
            metronome.setOnCompletionListener(null);
        }
    }
});
```

`postDelayed()` executes the code inside your Runnable after the number of milliseconds passed in the second parameter (`timetw`).

Comment: It says that methode postDelayed is not declared for MediaPlayer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `metronomepp.postDelayed()`.