# Android Timer changing interval

Tags: android, timer, intervals

I want to make a timer that changes a picture on the screen when the interval of the picture is over.

```
for(int x = 0; x < intervals.size(); x++)
            {
            t.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                @Override
                public void run() {      

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ImageView foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                                Bitmap bmp = sponsorlijst.get(index).getFoto();
                                foto.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                                if(index < sponsorlijst.size() -1)
                                {
                                    index ++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    index = 0;
                                }

                            }
                            }

                        ); 
                };}, 0, intervals.get(x));
```

Intervals are a list with the different displaytime of the pictures and the pictures are in sponsorlijst.

Does anyone know how to change the interval of the timer while running? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643177/changing-image-in-imageview-using-threads/16643564#16643564. Check the link

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Joliean why does it not fix the problem. You should know how to modify the same

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, I tried but in my example, it won't work

Comment: what din't work for you. post what you did and specify what din't work

Comment: I just can't top the timer, i tried it in the method "run" and also tried it afther the timer.schedule

Comment: if you want the timer to stop use timer.stop()

Comment: i know, but then i have to restart it, with a different interval.

Comment: i don't think you can do that. you will have to restart the timer again

Comment: So, I have to stop the timer with timer.stop() and then, below my first method t.schedule() i have to make a new timer with a different interval?

Comment: i din't understand clearly. Do you want to change the image every few seconds say 5 seconds??

Comment: No, every image has a different time to display. So after the first image's time is over, i want to set the time to display to the new time of the 2nd picture.