# My Android app splash screen launches in the android emulator, but then the actual app never shows

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

When i try to run my app, the splash screen comes up correctly, and right after it closes,  a message pops up that says "Unfortunatly, First app has stopped working" I've tried a ton of different solutions I've found but i believe in my case, it's a problem with my code after testing a new "Hello World" app within the emulator. Here's a copy of my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examle.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.firstapp.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVTY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is what comes up in log cat after trying some of the solutions

```
    06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firstapp.Splash" on path: /data/app/com.example.firstapp-1.apk
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firstapp.Splash" on path: /data/app/com.example.firstapp-1.apk
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-08 16:12:06.849: E/AndroidRuntime(2821):     ... 11 more
```

I'm really quite new to android programming, so if you could be specific when assisting me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow alright i didn't even realize that i made a typo in example. Another error is popping up though.


    `Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different case: '/FirstApp/bin/classes/com/examle/firstapp'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent FirstApp  Unknown Java Problem`

Comment: what's the package name in your java files?. Seems to be mismatch of the package name. is it like `package com.example.firstapp;`

Comment: The package name had caps in it, i just fixed it now. Now that error is gone, but now when i try to run the app, the splash screen doesn't show up at all, and it tells me it has stopped working.

Comment: did you try the edit's mentioned in my answer? Post he new logcat details of the crash

Comment: Yeah i tried them, no luck.

Comment: post the new logcat details of the crash

Comment: Alright i just edited the log cat the in main post because it was too long for the comments. So the log cat that's in the main post now, is what is showing up currently.

Comment: post the new manifest code also

Comment: also if you have updated your adt tool to rev 22. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra

Comment: Here it is, http://pastebin.com/7KgZvkk0

Comment: your manifest seems alright to me try the link i posted in the above comment

Comment: Well i downloaded the ADT Bundle about a week ago, so i'm not sure what version it is. Ill try updating it though.

Comment: Android SDK build Tools is at rev 17, android sdk tools is at rev 22.01

Comment: Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. Clean and Build.

Comment: Yeah it's checked, i cleaned and built the project, still i get a bunch of errors.

Comment: post those errors. i suggest you go through the link posted in my answer

Comment: I went through the intructions on the link and didn't get any results. Here are the errors http://pastebin.com/aTBRAyhE

Comment: post your java files also. i don't see anything wrong with the manifest file

Comment: Alright, here is my Splash.java

http://pastebin.com/7kGAM3S3

And here is my MainActivity.java

http://pastebin.com/4vAmMeZm

Btw, thanks for your help so far, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Alright so i believed i fixed several minor mistakes, so not the it goes to the splash screen fine, and then crashes. 

Here is my new MainActivity.xml
http://pastebin.com/AVypsYzv

Here is my new Splash.xml

http://pastebin.com/p7SxLhQA

Comment: Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.examle.firstapp.MAINACTIVITY"); should be   Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"); in your splash screen. using sleep inside a timer is bad design. use a handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643177/changing-image-in-imageview-using-threads/16643564#16643564.

Comment: i fixed what you suggested with the intent, still with no luck. I dont really want to change it to a handler just because i want to stick to the tutorial series I'm going through.

Comment: Alright so I've found that is i run MainACitvity without it going through the splash, it works, and when i run Splash, it works fine, but once it transitions to main activity, it stops working.

Comment: use a handler and try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643177/changing-image-in-imageview-using-threads/16643564#16643564. still have doubts start a new question. accept the below answer first and start a new thread. too much commenting leading to discussion

Comment: Alright i got it to work, one of the paths in the Finally statement wasn't the same as the path in the android manifest. Thanks for your help everyone, i appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it can't find your main activity because you have spelled the example wrong in your manifest on the line:

```
package="com.examle.firstapp"
```

should be:

```
package="com.example.firstapp"
```

Comment: You also need to make sure that the first line of your Java files, which also states the package, match the package name in your manifest. Make sure its consistant.

Comment: Turns out that i actually named the actual package file 'examle' and i didn't even realize it. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 5000);
    }


    class MyTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new  Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>`enter code here`
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the error lies in your manifest. The package name must be:

```
package="com.example.firstapp"
```

Also, for MainActivity, try to remove this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVTY"\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Splash in the default main activity to be launched. Your manifest should be

Your package name should be

```
 package="com.example.firstapp"
```

Activity

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"  
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you have explicit intents you can skip the intent filter

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"  
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

For more info check the link's below

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You can two step follow:
1. Uninstall previous (same) apps if install in your android phone.
2. Delete gen + bin folder
then again after a few time run your apps in your android phone.
Thanks