# Android/Java : Watch for variable change from main class

Tags: java, android, class

I wan't to check if variable is changed in my xClass from my main class.The thing is that, my variable only changes when the ImageView is clicked and that is running in a thread, so i wan't to check in a while loop (i don't know if that could be possible) in my main class when variable is changed do something.So this is what i tried, but when i run the program it just stops, and do nothing.

```
Thread setBack = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                knight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Counter++;
                        //also have some code here.
                    }
                }
};
```

So this is my thread and Counter is value that i want to watch.And i use get method, to return the value.

```
public boolean getCounter(){
            if(Counter>=1){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
}
```

So this indicates that value is changed (Counter is global variable).
And this is what i have done in my main class.

```
while (true) {
    if (xClass.getCounter()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is where my program actually stops running.And i can't think of any other way of getting indicator that value is changed.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In addition to everything else mentioned, make sure the variable is declared volatile.  Your overall approach sounds problematic - it would likely do better to have the background thread run something on the ui thread once the condition is met, so you avoid blocking the ui thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good choice for the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). What you would do here is to change the variable not via `Counter++` but rather with a function such as

```
private void incrementCounter() {
  Counter++;
  observer.notify();
}
```

Also add the following to your `xClass.java`:

```
private VariableChangeObserver observer;

public void register(VariableChangeObserver observer) {
  this.observer = observer;
}
```

Then you can have `Main.java` implement an interface such as the following:

```
public interface VariableChangeObserver {
  /**
   * Called whenever the variable is changed.
   */
  public void notify();
}
```

Last but not least, add a `notify()` function to your `Main.java` which does whatever you want to do when the value is updated.

**Additional info:**
Generally speaking, you would have a list of observers rather than just one. If you know however that you will only ever have one observer at any given time this should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `while(true)` runs in the main thread and it blocks the application.

Put it in a `Thread` and start it. That way it won't block the app, but will do what you want.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (xClass.getCounter()) {
                //your code
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Actually i did try that already, but i get exception that i need to use looper.prepare . And that is complicating things even more. A best solution that i would like is, that i only have a bool variable that will change when i click the image, and somehow to notify the main class that's changed.

Comment: Then you need an observer pattern. Fire a property change event when the variable changes, and register a property change listener wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautiful solution, but you can have a static boolean flag in xClass. Since you know that the variable's value is changed only after the imageview is clicked, you can set the flag=true soon after the variable is modified.

```
knight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Counter++;
        mainClassObject.callBackFunction();
        //also have some code here.
    }
}
```

And in the Main class you will need to define this call back function that will handle the variable changes.

```
public static callback(int newValue){
    //handle here
}
```

An infinite while loop should almost never be used as a solution to a practical problem. Prefer an event driven model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the intention of your code, so I'll try and answer to the best of my abilities.

1) I would recommend brushing up on you naming conventions. Names of objects that start in capitals are normally reserved for Class names e.g. View, Activity, CustomClass etc.
Since I assume your counter is a variable, I would call it 'counter' instead of 'Counter'.

2) It is actually fine to have the loop in the main 'thread' (I assume you are meaning thread, not class), if that is what you are intending to do, but be wary that it will block the main thread from doing anything else but performing that specific loop.

3) Dont forget, you have to call the start() function on the thread to actually get it to run the code.

4) When working on UI elements in a background thread, make sure you call any changes to the UI inside runOnUiThread(). Refer to [how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread).