# Which is best : runonuithread or asynctask android method : thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a question regarding the threads in Android programming language; 
what is the proper method to use in a thread to call the UI thread?
is it runOnUIthread method or AsyncTask method ?
with arguments please?
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: If you're already in a separate `Thread`, you want to use `runOnUiThread()`. `AsyncTask` is a separate way of handling threads in general.

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a facility providing a easy use of a Thread and the communication with the UI-Thread.

The method [runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread) is no Thread. It is used to communicate with the UI-Thread inside a background Thread. E.g. You have some calculation in a Thread and you want to update a View. To accomplish this you have to run the part, which is modifying the UI, on the UI-Thread. Therefor you can use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If it is a small one-off task like downloading a file over http then AsyncTask is probably going to be simpler to implement.

However, if you have a background thread running for a long time and need to publish updates to the view hierarchy before the task is finished, then runOnUiThread will be a good choice.

The key difference is that AsyncTask requires you to wait until your task is finished to publish updates.

EDIT: 
As Geobits points out, you do not have to wait until the task is complete to publish updates as AsyncTask has a publishProgress method for exactly that.

Comment: "The key difference is..." AsyncTask has a `onProgressUpdate()` method that runs on the UI thread and can be called from anywhere in `doInBackground()` via `publishProgress()`. It's misleading to say you must wait until the task is finished to publish updates.