# How do I update a TextView without causing the app to crash?

Tags: android

In a certain Activity have a `TextView` variable named timeText, which needs to be changed after 3 seconds have passed after the Activity was opened.

This is the code I wrote:

```
TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeText);
Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                timeText.setText("3");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
};
timer.start();
```

However this gave me this error: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable timeText inside an inner class defined in a different method"

So I changed the modifier of the `TextView` to `final` and tried again.
However, now the application crashes when this activity is started.

Comment: Try and use runOnUiThread. Here is an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot update ui from a non ui thrad

```
 timeText.setText("3");
```

Use `runOnUiThread` or `Handler`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeText.setText("3");

        }
    });
```

You can declare `timeText` as a instance variable and you need not have `final` modifier.

```
TextView timerText;
protectected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
  timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a handler and a runnable:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeText.setText("3");        
    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable , 3000);
```