# Android - False when make thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

[image]

I want: if user already put name and choose game types, user can click button 'OK' but if user doesn't already put name and choose game types, user can't click button 'OK'.

```
public class UserConfig extends Activity {
Button userConfigBack;
Button userConfigOK;
EditText userNameTextbox;
Spinner gameTypes;
private String gameType;
private String playerName;
private Handler handler;
Thread validation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.user_config);
     userConfigBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_config_back);
     userConfigOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_config_ok);
     userNameTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name_textbox);
     gameTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.game_types);
     gameTimes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.game_times);
     userConfigOK.setEnabled(false);
     userConfigOK.setClickable(false);
     setName();
     setGameType();
     handler = new Handler();
     autoValidation();
     OK();

}

public void setName() {
    playerName = userNameTextbox.getText().toString();

     userNameTextbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                playerName = userNameTextbox.getText().toString();
                nameLabel.setText(playerName);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            } 

        });


}

public void setGameType() {
    gameTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            gameType = (String) gameTypes.getSelectedItem();
            gameTypeLabel.setText(gameType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

}


public void OK() {

    userConfigOK.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserConfig.this, EnemyConfig1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}


public void autoValidation() {

    validation = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                         if(!gameType.equals("")) {
                             if(!playerName.equals("")) {
                                 userConfigOK.setEnabled(true);
                                 userConfigOK.setClickable(true);
                             }

                         }


                }
            });


        } 
    });
    validation.start();

}

}
```

I create thread inside method AUTOVALIDATION. If editText not null and user already choose game types spinner, user can click button OK. But

```
userConfigOK.setEnabled(true); 
userConfigOK.setClickable(true);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change any UI elements from another Thread. Try to use a `runOnUiThread` this should solve the problem.

You really should read this carefully: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html This will save you al lot of time if you are working with Threads.

And here is an example that helped me a lot:
[how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

Answer (score 0):

add a **`text watcher`** to your edittext and then use this  if elsestatement:

```
if(!userNameTextbox.getText().toString().equals("")){
 //do your job
}else{
//Toast some thing
}
```