# Can AsyncTask implement AnimationListener?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-asynctask, android-animation

I need to do play several animation asynchronously, so I've decided to implement AnimationListener with AsyncTask. Unfortunately it throws error `RuntimeException: An error acuured while executing doInBackground()` at the point I'm starting an animation. Is it possible to get it working with AsyncTask?

Code:
public class Game extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = Game.class.getSimpleName();

private Animation animation1;
private Animation animation2;
    ...
    ...
    ...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    // animations for turning cards
    this.animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
    this.animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
        ...
        ...
    AsyncTurn turn1 = new AsyncTurn(Game.this, position);
    turn1.execute();
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTurn extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> implements AnimationListener{

    private Context context;
    private int actPosition;

    public AsyncTurn(Context context, int position) {
        this.context = context;
        this.actPosition = position;
        animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ((ImageView) gridview.getChildAt(card1.getPosition())).clearAnimation();
            ((ImageView) gridview.getChildAt(card1.getPosition())).setAnimation(animation1);
                // ERROR AT NEXT LINE
            ((ImageView) gridview.getChildAt(card1.getPosition())).startAnimation(animation1);
    }
```

Comment: No UI stuff on background.

Comment: So what should I do? New Thread per animation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why u need AsyncTask anyway but u can use the AsyncTask function

```
void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)
```

in the `doInBackground()` call the function `publishProgrss()`

For Ref: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

or use runOnUIThread
Example : [RunOnUiThread Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

Comment: I need to separate variables for every animation and I don't see any other option.

Comment: instand of using AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> send the varibales here for example AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> ,  create a Holder Class for all the variables u need and send them to the AsyncTask

Comment: I think @dannyroa is right, the exception is thrown because I'm trying to do UI stuff in background. I need to find some other way how to run those animations separately. But which way...?