# crashing while calling invalidate in a seperate thread

Tags: android, canvas

Am new to Android and trying to call invalidate function repeatedly. So i choose thread to do that. My Thread is running properly but when tried to call invalidate () its crashing Below is the code snippet.

```
class MyCanvas extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "MY CANVAS EXAMPLE";

    public MyCanvas(Context context){
        super(context);
        Log.e ( TAG, " MY CANVAS CONSTRUCTOR GOT CALLED ");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Thread newBackground = new Thread ( new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    invalidate();
                    Log.e ( TAG, " MY THREAD GOT CALLED ");
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        newBackground.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.e ( TAG, " MY CANVAS GOT CALLED ");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }       
}
```

and below is the crash log observed

```
09-23 17:41:09.299: E/MY CANVAS EXAMPLE(1839):  MY CANVAS CONSTRUCTOR GOT CALLED 
09-23 17:41:09.599: E/MY CANVAS EXAMPLE(1839):  MY CANVAS GOT CALLED 
09-23 17:41:10.329: W/dalvikvm(1839): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578) 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3020) 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:647) 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:673) 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511) 
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)     
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at com.example.canvas.MainActivity$MyCanvas$1.run(MainActivity.java:83)
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

`invalidate()` can only be called on the main UI thread.

Don't use a thread for such delays. Instead, consider using a `Handler` with `postDelayed()` to post a `Runnable` to run on the main UI thread after the delay.

(There's also `postInvalidate()` in case you want to post an `invalidate()` message from a background thread if you insist on using a separate thread. Not using a separate thread is a better option.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the method `invalidate()` isn't allowed to be run outside the main (UI) thread. If you read the details of the Exception you've got then you could see this :

```
09-23 17:41:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1839): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

To fix it, simply run `invalidate()` on the main thread by using `runOnUiThread()`method. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread) should provide you more information as of how.

***edit:*** A more elegant solution is to call `postInvalidate()` as described by BlackBelt. This way you wouldn't have to create a new `Runnable` instance. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate();` schedule a redesign of the view hierarchy which, in turn, can be only accessed by the UI Thread and not from your background thread. You should use `postInvalidate()`. From the documentation

> Cause an invalidate of the specified area to happen on a subsequent
>   cycle through the event loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a
>   non-UI thread.