# Infinite while loop inside a Fragment that returns the LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android-fragments, while-loop, layout-inflater

I want to infinitely loop a method when in the Main Fragment, but I keep getting issues saying the return or the loop is unreachable or I may throw and exception.
Should I be using try / catch / finally?

Any ideas help!

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

return v;

while (true) { // This line is unreachable

    aMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run code after a return statement. The function has ended. Consider changing your loop to break on a condition, and to return after your loop has terminated.

EDIT: Using a thread

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
            yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    doStuff();
                }
            });
    }
}.start();
return returnVal;
```

Comment: That's the thing. It will never terminate. I want it to loop forever.

Comment: I've tried one and it didn't work. (I may have written it incorrectly) Could you write an example?

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

The while statement cannon complete without throwing an exception.

Comment: @Mike, you cannot make changes to the ui from another thread. Now you need `yourActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable yourRunnable)`. Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread. I have updated my answer with an example as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67035/discussion-between-mike-milla-and-meettitan).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach a statement after returning v:

```
return v; //Everyting after this is unreachable because you return

for (int f = 1; f > 0; f++) { // This line is unreachable

    logo.startAnimation(flipInAnimation);
    logo.startAnimation(flipOutAnimation);

}
```

Comment: I am aware of that.

How would you recommend I get around it?

Comment: Uhm, if you are running an infinite loop you can never return something after that unless you beak out of the loop.

Comment: Then, as @MeetTitan suggested, use a thread. He provided a good example. Your question was really vague and this is what I thought you were asking.