# Calculate time thread android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, android-wallpaper

I'm using a thread to set an image as background and in this thread i have a dialog. The dialog starts and should be close when the wallpaper will be set. This is the code so far

```
setWallbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(SingleWall.this, "Setting wallpaper", "", true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                            try {
                                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                wallManager.setBitmap(image);
                                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Wallpaper Set Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                myPd_ring.dismiss();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                myPd_ring.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 4000);


            }
        });
```

So, on click in a button starts the thread and for 4 seconds the dialog should be visible with the progress icon. But it is not correct! the time to set the background could be more or less than 4 seconds! So the `4000` should be calculates in base of the time to set the image as wallpaper. Is it possible?

ps. I can't use a AsyncTask because i get many `NullPointerExceptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are not using a separate Thread with the code in your question, you are running a `Runnable` on the main UI thread.

If you look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html), it's recommended to use an `AsyncTask` for decoding Bitmaps, and it's also the best way to  achieve your desired result, where the ProgressDialog is dismissed only after the process is complete, which can take an unpredictable amount of time.

You just need to put the code in it's correct place, and give it what it needs through the `varargs` passed in.

Here is how you should start the `AsyncTask`:

```
    setWallbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           new LoadImage().execute(url);
        }
    });
```

Then, create the `AsyncTask` as a sub-class of the `SingleWall` Activity.
Put the network code in `doInBackground()` which will download and decode the Bitmap, and then put the UI related code in `onPostExecute()`, which runs on the UI thread.

Note that you can also use a `WeakReference` to the `WallpaperManager` instance, as outlined in the link above, but I'll keep it simple here and just access `wallManager` directly, which you can do if the `AsyncTask` is a sub-class of your Activity.

```
class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

    ProgressDialog myPd_ring;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Start Progress Dialog here
        myPd_ring = ProgressDialog.show(SingleWall.this, "Setting wallpaper", "", true);
    }

    //Runs in a background Thread
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
        URL url = params[0];
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    //Runs on the UI Thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        myPd_ring.dismiss();

        if (image == null){
            Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            //set image here
            try {
                SingleWall.this.wallManager.setBitmap(image);

                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Wallpaper Set Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @End.Game I just realized that I had the success toast in the wrong place, there was a chance for a failure and a success Toast. Just updated the answer with the small fix.

Comment: yes now it's perfect!! Only one more thing..the progress dialog disappear little bit before the success toast..is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Use the AsyncTask, the null pointers are probably coming because you are trying to update the UI during the task's processing.  You might need to use something like this from inside the AsyncTask:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            activity.doSomeSpecialUIWork();
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that works - that's what solved it for me when I was getting strange null pointers during an AsyncTask.

Here's an example from another post: [how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

For your specific code, maybe this:

```
setWallbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(SingleWall.this, "Setting wallpaper", "", true);
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                            try {
                                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                wallManager.setBitmap(image);
                                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Wallpaper Set Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                myPd_ring.dismiss();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(SingleWall.this, "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                myPd_ring.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```