# How do I update google map marker position in a separate thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, api, google-maps, marker

I am trying to update a google map marker position in a separate thread. I can update the marker fine in the main thread, but as soon as I try it in a separate thread, the app crashes.

Logcat:

```
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2909
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.l.a.ce.b(Unknown Source)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ct.a(Unknown Source)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aq.a(Unknown Source)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.t.onTransact(SourceFile:73)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzi$zza$zza.setPosition(Unknown Source)
06-10 12:35:37.107: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setPosition(Unknown Source)
```

and the thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    Marker mkr = marker;
    public void run(){
        double lng = 78.486671;
        double lat = 17.385044;
        mkr.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: As the error states, you cannot update markers off of the main UI thread. What are you trying to accomplish by doing it on a separate thread?

Comment: Im tracking something and need to mark its position on a map. The lng and lat of the object will keep changing and I would like to update a marker to point to its location.

Comment: You could use `runOnUiThread()` in order to modify the Marker position inside your worker thread, for an example see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread/11140429#11140429

Comment: !!!GREAT EXAMPLE!!! works great, thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `runOnUiThread()` in order to modify the Marker position inside your worker thread, for an example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread/11140429#11140429).

In your case it would be something like this:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Marker mkr = marker;
        public void run(){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    double lng = 78.486671;
                    double lat = 17.385044;
                    mkr.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
```