# AsyncTask --- An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int progress = 0;

        publishProgress(progress += 10);

        String[] link_list = new String[100];
        Bitmap bmp ;
        Document xmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

            Elements title = xmlDoc.select("div[class=meta]");

            title_lenth = title.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < title_lenth; i++) {
                link_list[count] = title.get(i).text();
                try{
                    JSONObject JObj_link ;
                    JObj_link = new JSONObject(link_list[count]);
                    link_list[count] = JObj_link.getString("ou");
                    Log.e("ou Content", link_list[count]);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("ou Content", e.toString());
                }
                    System.out.print(titlelist[count]);
                    count ++ ;
            }
            setBmp(link_list);
            publishProgress(progress += 15);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(progress = 100);

        return title_word;
    }
```

I deleted some code Not critical

I want to do

-> setBmp(link_list);

- link_list is a string array content urls (http://xxx.xx.jpg)
- the setbmp can download pics and set imageview

now there is error messages

Logcat :

```
03-10 09:32:23.461  16218-16493/com.takepickpicturedemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.takepickpicturedemo, PID: 16218
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5081)
            at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12713)
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12677)
            at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12661)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1996)
            at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:194)
            at com.takepickpicturedemo.MainActivity.setBmp(MainActivity.java:741)
            at com.takepickpicturedemo.MainActivity$GetPredict.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:582)
            at com.takepickpicturedemo.MainActivity$GetPredict.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:497)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

edit

so ..

1. Main thread cannot do Network
2. doInBackground cannot setting UI

How can I do to download & change UI

Comment: *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views*--it means that you manipulate UI outside UI thread, which is not allowed. Use `runOnUiThread()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread

Comment: probably something happens in your setBMP which shouldn't and that probably updating a view

Comment: You cant access UI in doInBackground() method, your setBmp() accesses UI, then the error is raised by this. You can do UI work after task is completed in onPostExecuteMethod(), or call UI Thread as runOnUiThread(YOUR_THREAD).

Answer (score 2):

As I see, `setBmp()` method calls a UI update. A UI update should occur in the UI thread. You should know that `doInBackground` occurs in a background thread and **not** the UI thread.

Instead of calling it in the `doInBackground` method, try calling `setBmp()` from `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`.

NOTE: `onPostExecute` method is executed in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs because `setBmp()` somehow affects views, which is not allowed on other threads than UI thread. Wrappping it with `runOnUiThread()` will help. Replace the line

```
setBmp(link_list);
```

by:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setBmp(link_list);
    }
});
```

To make it work, you also should make `link_list` final on creation:

```
final String[] link_list = new String[100];  // "final" added
```

Comment: not also, it's another exception. Please post `setBmp()` code in your question

Answer (score -2):

Here is you **setBmp(link_list);** Method. May be this Method Try to show Image. `**doInBackground**` method do not created a view.

Thanks