# Android BottomSheetBehavior setState() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm trying to implement `BottomSheetBehavior` from Android Support Design Library. I initialize `BottomSheetBehavior` like this:

```
private void initBottomSheet() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            View bottomSheetFrame = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetFrame);

                bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                    private boolean isOnTop = false;

                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                        switch (newState) {

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING: {
                                ...
                            }

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING: {
                                ...
                            }

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                               ...
                            }

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                                ...
                            }

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN: {
                                ...
                            }

                            default: {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                        ...
                });

                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(100f, activityContext));
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN); // NPE here

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

It's very strange, because I can change state with `Button` click or some other action. Please, help me.

Comment: Remove this line View bottomSheetFrame = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet); outiside of async task, and make find the view inside onCreate method. Also if you are updating a view you should do in onPostExecute method.

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás, thank you very much. I event didn't notice method is called from `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem**

NPE happens because you call `BottomSheetBehavior.setState(...)` before your view — `bottomSheetFrame` was laid out. At this moment BottomSheetBehavior have `null` reference on the view and can't apply your state to it.

**Solution**

I fixed this by using `View.post(Runnable)` method:

```
View sheetView = ... ;    
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(sheetView);
int initState = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED;

sheetView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        behavior.setState(initState);
    }
});
```

In my situation this helped to stop NPE-s :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for reply. Nice solution, but in my case I need just put code out of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Great solution, you saved me from an afternoon of frustration :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in a `Fragment`, just be sure to call it on the `onCreateView()` method. And if you are using it on an `Activity`, then call it at the `onCreate()` method.

At those points, your Views have to be already created, unless you are creating them programmatically.

Since you are calling methods that are related with the UI from an `AsyncTask`, then you'll need to surround it with the `runOnUiThread` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992603/973919

Basically, you need to call to anything that is related with views, from the main thread of the app, which is the UI thread.