# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

i got an error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create()' on a null object reference` everytime i build my app

here's code of my error

```
07-26 15:04:32.587 18897-18915/com.example.study E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-385
Process: com.example.study, PID: 18897
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create()' on a null object reference
     at com.example.study.Splash.checking(Splash.java:66)
     at com.example.study.Splash$2.run(Splash.java:51)
```

it happened on my splash activity, here's my code

```
package com.example.study;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.study.helper.SessionManager;
import com.example.study.util.ConnectionDetector;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    protected SessionManager session;

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        builder.setTitle("No Connection");
        builder.setMessage("Check Your Internet Connection.");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.fail);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    /* TODO Auto-generated method stub */
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    checking();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public void checking() {

        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        if(isInternetPresent) {
            session.checkLogin();
            finish();
        } else {
            builder.create().show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

dunno what to do ... please help to solve this problem,

Comment: Post some code please for your splash screen :)

Comment: No, I mean, just copy your code in your splash screen, edit your question, and paste the code onto your question, that way People can see your code and help you with it :)

Comment: oh my .. i tried .. but always said error on code.. and keep trying now

Comment: Ohh so that's what you mean, maybe it's not well formatted?

Comment: @kevin Finally, let me get some help from you if you could to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it fails at your `checking()` method. You have declared a global variable named `builder`, then you declared another variable inside your `onCreate()`. In your `checking()` method, it refers to the global variable which you didn't initialize, only declare.

Possible solution, edit this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
```

to

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
```

Comment: 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()' happened at my 'checking();'

Comment: Ah I think it's because your builder is started from outside of Main Thread which is the UI thread (I forgot the fancy names), I am currently Googling stuffs, use keyword `Alertdialog in Handler` for reference

Comment: I can't find any good answer and this might be a bit hacky and I don't know it might work buy worth trying, try using `runOnUiThread()` method like described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread, and may I know what's the purpose of `finish()` after `builder.create().show();`?

Comment: `finish()` this is for the activity.. means close the activity after the alert dialog positive button was pressed ... or let me know if i was wrong ..

Comment: If you do `finish()` after `show()`, it'll finish the activity, right after showing the alertdialog.. You should add `finish()` right after `dialog.dismiss();` in your `Dialog` `OK` button method.. I'm sorry but I can only help you that much as I am not so proficient at using handlers

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this below code for reference, it's working fine for me.**

> Before onCreate()

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
```

> Within OnCreate()

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

> Create AlertDialog

```
alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to continue ?");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       //write your code here after click yes
    }
});
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
     }
});
alertDialog.show();
```