# Error using setText in runInUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I need a thread that waits some time then changes a text in a TextView.
My search found [how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

I understood the first answer and tried to use it in my code but I get an error when calling setText in the thread.

Here is my code 
(start is the onClick function of a button):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int i = 0;
    private TextView mText;
    private Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    public void start (View v) {
        runThread();


    }

    private void runThread() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                i++;
                                mText.setText((i));
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Here is my error

```
09-26 20:26:34.054 22254-22254/com.horizon.testtimerthread E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1058)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3866)
                                                                                 at com.horizon.testtimerthread.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mText.setText((i))` is the problem.

Android thinks that you are referencing a String ID and is crashing because it cannot find a String with an ID of 1. If you meant to set the text to "1", "2" ect... then write `mText.setText((Integer.toString(i)))`

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. Yes it works thank you.

Comment: No worries ;) You'll use this in the future as an example of how much you've grown

Answer (score 1):

Since `i` has type int, you are calling `setText(int resourceId)` variant of function, what is obvious not you want. `setText(String.valueOf(i))` should work.