# How to change listview item text color and image color from handler

Tags: java, android

I am new for android, I have `ListView` with custom adapter, I pass one string if matches in `ListView` item want to change list item text color from `Activity`.

Here my code:

MyActivity:

```js
public void handleResult(String rawResult) {     
        if(Utility.isNotNull(rawResult.getText().toString())) {
            for(int i=0;i<listView.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                if(rawResult.equals(listItems.get(i).getStockItems())){         
                 // listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.hint));       
                    
                    /* Here I want to change list item text color*/
                    
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                             
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model class add one paramter like this

```
      public class DataHolder{

        private String StockItems;
        private int isSelected;

        public DataHolder(String StockItems, int isSelected) {
            this.StockItems = StockItems;
            this.isSelected = isSelected;

        }

        public String getStockItems() {
            return StockItems;
        }

        public void setStockItems(String StockItems) {
            this.StockItems = StockItems;
        }

        public int getiIsSelected() {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public void setIsSelected(String isSelected) {
            this.isSelected = isSelected;
        }
    }
```

initialise IsSelected zero

```
    public void handleResult(String rawResult) {    
            if(Utility.isNotNull(rawResult.getText().toString())) {
                for(int i=0;i<listView.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                    if(rawResult.equals(listItems.get(i).getStockItems())){   
                        listItems.get(i).setIsSelected(1);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                      
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In your cusom adapter class check

```
      if(listItems.get(i).getiIsSelected()==1)
      {
            //set red text color
      }
      else
      {
            //set black text color
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

UI tasks can only be done on the UI Thread. If u want to run it from the handler, you have to define a runOnUiThread method. Take a look at this ans

[how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<listView.getChildCount();i++) {
  // yours code
  View item = listView.getChildAt(i);
  item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);  //change image
    ((TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setTextColor(Color.RED);   //text1 is your cusotm listview item's  text id
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `TextView` , To change his text color, first you need to get him, when you create your Item, add id to `TextView`

with xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myId"...
```

Or if you use java

```
textView.setId(R.id.myId)
```

and in your code :

```
((TextView)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.myId)).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.hint));
```

If you want to set the Item Background with your Drawble Image you can use 
.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourDrawble));

Answer (score 0):

Make one method in your Adapter class to update text color and create one flag in Adapter that is initially false ,Use below method to do this

```
boolean isChangeColor = false;
String  colorCode = "#FFFFFF";

private void updateTextColor(boolean isChangeColor , String colorCode) {
    this.isChangeColor=isChangeColor;
    this.colorCode=colorCode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();         
}
```

And in getView()

```
if(isChangeColor) {
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode));
} else {
    colorCode = "#FFFFFF";
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode));
}
```