# Trying to change TextView text inside asynctask

Tags: android, json

I would like to change the text from a TextView when a JSON array is empty.

This is the code where I am getting the JSON array:

```
private void getEntrenadoresFromDB(int id) {

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... entrenadoresIds) {
                Log.d("CEF", "WORKOUT SELECCIONADO: " + workout_seleccionado);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://....php?id=" + workout_seleccionado)
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());





                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        int numeroentrenadores = array.length();
                        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "NUMERO ENTRENADORES: " + numeroentrenadores);
                        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "NUMERO ENTRENADORES: " + numeroentrenadores);
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ENTRENADORES", "ENTRENADOR LEIDO: " + object.getString("imagen_art"));
                        Entrenador entrenador = new Entrenador(object.getInt("id_entrenador"), object.getString("corto"),object.getString("largo"),
                                object.getInt("sexo"),object.getString("ciudad"), object.getString("imagen_art"),
                                object.getString("nombre_art"),object.getString("usuario"), object.getInt("workout"), object.getDouble("latitud_entrenador"), object.getDouble("longitud_entrenador"));
                        entrenadores.add(entrenador);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "NUMERO ENTRENADORES: " +"no hay entrenadores io exception");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "NUMERO ENTRENADORES: " +"no hay entrenadores json exception");
                    txtNo.setText("h");

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }
```

As you may see, I have tried putting it under catch (JSONException e), but there is a warning: setText must be called from the UI thread...
What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method setText must be called from the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924166/method-settext-must-be-called-from-the-ui-thread)

Comment: @AhamadAnees, the question is not to do it under the asyctask, the question is about to know when the JSON array is empty

Comment: you are already checking the size of array. and changing ui elements from non ui thread is error but not warning and for which people have alreadt responded. What exactly is the issue again?

Comment: @MohammedAtif, if the array, then   is empty  int numeroentrenadores = array.length(); is not executed.

Comment: obviously right, that line is inside for loop, if your length is 0, for loop wont loop at all.

Comment: @mvasco have you read my answer?

Comment: @Vyacheslav, yes. I am on it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but there is a warning: setText must be called from the UI thread... What should I do?

Yes, the `setText` method should be called from the UI thread. So you can call it from `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` instead of `doInBackground(Integer... entrenadoresIds)`. Make the `doInBackGround` method return the array size so that you can compare the value in the `onPostExecute(Integer result)`

```
if(array!=null && array.length()>0){
   //do your stuff here
   return array.length();
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, but  I need to know when the array is empty

Comment: @mvasco it's dead simple. make the doInBackground method return array size instead of null when the json Array is not empty. So you can compare it later in the onPostExecute right? :)

Comment: I would like to implement your answer, but I don´t know how to return array size instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Ui related things from doInBackground, they have to be called in onPreExecute or in onPostExecute. If you want to change the text if it failed, change the returntype of  doInBackground from void to boolean and return false, if it was successful and true if it failed. Then, in onPostExecute check if it failed or not and set the text accordingly. If you want distinguish between different errors, use String instead of boolean.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know if the JSON array is empty.

Comment: You can also check that at the end of doInBackground and return true if it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Change your code by this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

if (array.length() == 0) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      textView.setText("your message");       
                   }
                });
}
```

***EDIT***

note: `runOnUiThread` is a method of `Activity` class

Comment: @mvasco getEntrenadoresFromDB - where this method is placed?

Comment: Solved, it is a fragment, I have to add getActivity().runOnUiThread

Comment: It is not working, since array is empty your proposal is never called. At least where you say to put it.

Comment: @mvasco post your data you receive

Comment: @mvasco `array.length() == 0` means your array is empty

Comment: yes, but if I put it inside the try loop, if the array is empty, the try loop is not called

Comment: @mvasco what do you mean 'try loop'. It is difficult to understand you

Comment: @mvasco i've shown how to check whether the array is empty and how to set text of the textview

Comment: I know, but I can hardly check for    if (array.length() == 0)    if it is never called