# Implementing Search filter in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose you are showing list of movies.

You are offering a filter (as a separate activity)
(Filter window could be overlayed on top of the list of movies (not sure how I could do this in android)

Now user selects filters in the filter screen, and wants to apply the filter.

The filter data should be transfered from the filter activity to the previous activity (which shows the movie lists).

How can I pass the data in this scenario?

Should I use some kind of event system (such as NotificationCenter in ios)?
Or should I use some form of `startActivity` even though the activity is already started and waiting.

Comment: In android its a bit simple. When you are using a seperate Activity for filter, start the activity with startActivityForResult. Once You are done selecting filter values, finish that activity and the onResult method will be called in previous activity which had your list. You can filter the list there. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you want to open a particular `Activity` to get result back in previous `Activity`, Best practice according to me is use `startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)` instead of `startActivity(intent)`.
2. Override following method is your 1st activity where you wish to receive data
   `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`
3. In order to get result back on 1st Activity, following code should be triggered in 2nd Activity

   ```
           Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
           resultIntent.putExtra("data", yourData); //make 'yourData' Serializable if a POJO
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
           finish();
   ```
4. After this code triggers you will get callback in `onActivityResult()` in your 1st activity where you called `startActivityForResult()` with whatever `extars` you put. Hope this helps. GL

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `Runnable` interface and add UI changes you wish to perform inside the `run` method. Then instantiate and send it to the main UIThread with [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). Your changes will then take place in the main activity (where you have a list of movies).

Example of [how to use runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread).