# Updating main thread from new Runnable class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to dynamically update an android `LinearLayout` in the main thread.

Unfortunately I'm having a lot of trouble ascertaining anything from the tutorials online. None of them seem to provide a complete picture of how to communicate between threads.

My idea is something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        setContentView(layout);

        Updater updater = new Updater();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(updater);
        //somehow update layout
```

The updater class would look something like this:

```
public class Updater implements Runnable {

    private int count = 0;

    public Updater() {}

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){

            try {
                count++;
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I need a `Handler` in order to communicate messages between the threads, but I don't know how to set that up.

I would like to avoid anonymous classes, and dynamically create new `TextView`s whenever `Updater` has a new message.

Comment: You can try `AsyncTask` though if your only job is process a certain thing in the background and pass it back to the MainThread!

Comment: What is `Updater`? Your Runnable class name is `Counter` isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid that though since I need to continuously update a `View`, and I don't think using the "progress" method would be best for performance. Also, I'd like to know how to properly set up the threading myself.

@ADM sorry, it was a typo!

Comment: It seems your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread. Or you can use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: @LQGioan The whole point of this is to spawn a second thread, since my UI thread is extremely slow and unresponsive

Comment: Linked question had more useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create `WorkerThreadListener` interface:

> ```
> public interface WorkerThreadListener {
>     void onUpdate(int counter);
> }
> ```

2. Change your `Updater` class:

> ```
> public class Updater implements Runnable {
>
>     private final WorkerThreadListener mWorkerThreadListener;
>     private final Handler mHandler;
>
>     private int count = 0;
>
>     public Updater(final WorkerThreadListener workerThreadListener) {
>         this.mWorkerThreadListener = workerThreadListener;
>         this.mHandler = new Handler();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>             try {
>                 count++;
>                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void run() {
>                         mWorkerThreadListener.onUpdate(count);
>                     }
>                 });
>                 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
>             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Change `MainActivity` class:

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     private LinearLayout layout;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         layout = new LinearLayout(this);
>         setContentView(layout);
>         Updater updater = new Updater(new WorkerThreadListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onUpdate(int counter) {
>                 //update layout here
>             }
>         });
>         Thread workerThread = new Thread(updater);
>         workerThread.start();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check my below answer hope it helps you.

```
public class ProgressTestActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    public void startProgress(View view) {
        // do something long
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                    final int value = i;
                     doFakeWork();
                    progress.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           // here you can add any view or anyof your logic which is related to UI put it into here.
                            text.setText("Updating");
                            progress.setProgress(value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    // Simulating something timeconsuming
    private void doFakeWork() {
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Other ways are also possible.if you have any doubt please comment below post i will explain you in details.

Comment: How would this be done without anonymous classes? I also don't want to use `ProgressBar`. I actually want to add a new `TextView` with the current `count` to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a tick timer and set progress to ui thread . You can use `CountDownTimer`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private TextView textView;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    findViewById(R.id.b2).setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void processData() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("done!");
        }

    }.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    processData();
}
}
```

Apart from that to post a callback on UI thread you can use Handler .

```
 Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I used this as an easy example. The problem I'm trying to solve is much more broad than just a timer. I really want to know how to create a separate thread that can be used to update a `View`, updating in real time.

Comment: See the updated answer if you are dealing with callback from NonUi thread to UI thread .