# Use SimpleDraweeView to show local image error reporting

Tags: android, image, fresco

When I use SimpleDraweeView to show local images,something went wrong

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+data);
 simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

The error is

```
UncaughtException detected: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.facebook.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:158)
at com.facebook.drawee.components.DeferredReleaser.ensureOnUiThread(DeferredReleaser.java:101)
at com.facebook.drawee.components.DeferredReleaser.cancelDeferredRelease(DeferredReleaser.java:96)
at com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeController.onAttach(AbstractDraweeController.java:358)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeHolder.attachController(DraweeHolder.java:264)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeHolder.attachOrDetachController(DraweeHolder.java:281)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeHolder.onAttach(DraweeHolder.java:93)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeView.doAttach(DraweeView.java:180)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeView.onAttach(DraweeView.java:166)
at com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeView.onAttachedToWindow(DraweeView.java:140)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14798)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2969)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2969)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2969)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2969)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1618)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6809)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
```

I don't know what the mistake was.The uri is effective.

Comment: Can you edit your post with some context (programing language, framework, ...). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allowed to update the view from within the UI Thread, not from other threads. You can fix the exception by updating the component from the UI thread instead:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> theMethodThatUpdatesYourImage());
```

See also the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-do-we-use-runonuithread-in-android) for reference.

Comment: Its no matter use,but use ImageView is ok.