# AsyncTask does not update UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this AsyncTask after it is called by another one `OnPostExecute()` Method and this is the code

```
class GetDataTask_image extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        public GetDataTask_image() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            GetDataTask_out.Status.values();
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /* Show checking image */
            Cursor data_image = Sync.get_image(current_email);
            int image_count = data_image.getCount();
            while (data_image.moveToNext()) {
                String folder = data_image.getString(data_image.getColumnIndex("folder"));
                String file_name = data_image.getString(data_image.getColumnIndex("myimage"));

                JSONObject unsync_image1 = new JSONObject();
                FilePathname = sdCardDirectory + "/" + file_name;
                File file = new File(FilePathname);
                Context c = data_syncing_v3.this;
                File directory = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                String imgpath = directory + "/" + file_name;
                fileName = imgpath;

                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        unsync_image1.put("module", folder);
                        unsync_image1.put("name", file_name);
                        unsync_image1.put("tag", 1);
                        unsync_images1.put(unsync_image1);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        unsync_image1.put("module", folder);
                        unsync_image1.put("name", file_name);
                        unsync_image1.put("tag", 0);
                        unsync_images1.put(unsync_image1);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
                    }
                }
                Log.e("file_name", file_name);
            }

            final String data = unsync_images1.toString();
            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, master_link_forimage,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.e("tagconvertstr", "[" + response + "]");
                            try {
                                obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                sync_data = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                                if (sync_data.length() == 0) {
                                    /* Close dialog */
                                    p = (float) index / (float) sync_data.length();
                                    p = p + p * (float) 50;
                                    publishProgress((int) p);
                                } else {
                                    Context c = data_syncing_v3.this;
                                    final File directory = c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                                    final StringBuilder data_image = new StringBuilder("");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < sync_data.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject sync_object = sync_data.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String procedure = sync_object.getString("procedure").toString();
                                        String link = sync_object.getString("link").toString();
                                        String file_name = sync_object.getString("file").toString();
                                        String folder = sync_object.getString("folder_name").toString();

                                        if (procedure.toString().equals("up")) {
                                            /* Upload file */
                                            String imgpath = directory + "/" + file_name;
                                            fileName = imgpath;
                                            final File findfile = new File(imgpath);
                                            imgPath = directory + "/" + findfile.getName();
                                            fileName = findfile.getName();
                                            image_view.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath));
                                            image_view.buildDrawingCache();
                                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image_view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
                                            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                                            ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                            data_image.append(folder + "**cut_here**" + fileName.toString() + "**cut_here**" + ConvertImage + "**new_line**");
                                        } else {
                                            /* Download file */
                                            String main_link = "MY LINK FOR DOWNLOAD";
                                            FilePathname = sdCardDirectory + "/" + file_name;
                                            DownloadFilesname(FilePathname, main_link);
                                        }

                                        if (i == (sync_data.length() - 1)) {
                                            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uploader,
                                                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                            Log.e("MYAPP", "[" + response + "]");
                                                        }
                                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                    Log.e("MYAPP", "3");
                                                    back_holder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                }
                                            }) {
                                                @Override
                                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                                    params.put("image_data", data_image.toString());
                                                    return params;
                                                }
                                            };
                                            VolleySingleton.getInstance(data_syncing_v3.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                                        }
                                        index++;
                                        p = (float) index / (float) sync_data.length();
                                        p = p + p * (float) 50;
                                        publishProgress((int) p);
                                        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception 11111");
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    /* TODO : In case there is an error */
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "1");
                    back_holder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("email", current_email);
                    params.put("data", data);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mProgressAnimation.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

The function of this code is to check 1st if the image exist in the folder then if not it will upload/download the image from the server depends if it is exist or not.

My problem is i have a progress the must update or increment but nothing happens whats the problem?

Comment: run your code inside runOnUIThread.

Comment: how? I didnt try that before

Comment: look at this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-do-we-use-runonuithread-in-android

Comment: on what part i will add that?

Comment: the Ui update part.

Comment: update of what sir? the one on progressUpdate?

Comment: it's not related to Async task it's about UI refresh

Comment: @Mr.AF where in my code should i add that

Comment: you must refresh your UI in main thread .

Answer (score 3):

when you are using multithreading in your app, you have to use "runOnUiThread" function for updating Views

based on Android Developers Doc :

```
Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI 
thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not 
the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.
```

so in your case you have to do something like this :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            publishProgress((int) p);
        }
    });
```

runOnUiThread is a function from Activity Class so incase that you are not inside a activity you have to pass the Context and use something like

```
mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        publishProgress((int) p);
    }
});
```

Comment: i will bring an example that your code is wrong in some cases.your answer is the basic common answer

Comment: @Mr.AF sure Sir, there is a Exceptions for every scenario :)

Comment: still i dont know where i will add that

Comment: @myownemail please consider accepting the answer if the answer was helpful :)

Comment: @RasoolGhana hi and good morning and also merry Christmas actually the code u provide really updates the UI but the whole process doesnt completely done making the app hangs. Let me fix the whole process using ur code then i will accept it :)