# Where to call Handler Class's constructor in activity lifecycle

Tags: android, handler, android-lifecycle

I'm a beginner to android, so sorry in advance for any mistakes.

So I have an activity in which I have a handler to execute a message. Now I don't know where should I call the constructor of this handler in the activity life cycle. Should it be in the activity's constructor or `onCreate()` or `onInit()`, which one would be most suitable.
I have this handler's static object to be initialised so I guess it won't be suitable to call it in activity's constructor.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method called `onInit` in Activity's life cycle and we do not use a constructor in `Activity` either .

`Activity` is a component of android its object is initialize by OS itself whenever we call `startActivity`.

Now for your answer you can initialize `Handler` inside `#onCreate()`.  You can also use [runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-do-we-use-runonuithread-in-android) for limited purpose. Try not to use `static`
 properties .

```
class A extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Other stuff
        handler=new Handler();
    }
}
```